# Facebook getLoginUrl for canvas

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas, facebook-login

I have a canvas app in facebook, and I'm using the code:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
    'canvas'    => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,offline_access'

));
```

However all the time when a user clicks the "Go To App" button it redirects straight back to my app not in facebook, but in fact the full URL.

How can I make it go back to the app page?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the answer was fairly simple.

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
    'canvas'    => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,offline_access',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://uri'

));
```

However if you have Canvas App selected in app settings that redirect_uri must be the same as the url set for Canvas App.

If it is just a page tab, you can redirect to anything

Comment: What is the answer? What does "http://uri" stand for? Using exactly what you wrote here just results in an error on Facebook.

Comment: uri will be the URL of the app page. Essentially `"redirect_uri" => "{your url to redirect to here}"`